# How to get this variational equation and this linearization?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system:
$$
u'=v,~~~~~v'=-cv-f(u)+w,~~~~~w'=-(\epsilon / c)(u-\gamma w).
$$

Here, $f(u)=u(u-a)(1-u),~a< 1/2$ and $\varepsilon,\gamma$ are positive.

Here are two results I do not understand how to get them:

**(1)**

> > Let $S_{\epsilon}=(u_{\epsilon}, v_{\epsilon}, w_{\epsilon})$ be a solution. Consider the variational equations:
> >     $$
> > \delta u'=\delta v',~~~~~\delta v'=-c\delta v - f'(u_{\epsilon})\delta u+\delta w,~~~~~\delta w'=-(\epsilon /c) (\delta u - \gamma\delta w).~~~ (*)
> > $$

**(2)**

> > $(*)$ is well approximated by the system linearized at $U_1=(u_1,v_1,w_1)$ (this is a special point of the phase space) with $\epsilon =0$:
> >     $$
> > \delta u' = \delta v,~~~~~\delta v'=-c\delta v-f'(u_1)\delta u+\delta w,~~~~~\delta w'=0.~~~(**)
> > $$

1. I would like to know how to get $(*)$ and $(**)$.
2. Is variational equation and linearization the same?

Comment: The second question requires knowledge of what do you mean by "linearization". If I'm not mistaken, essentially variational equation and linearization are the same: take a solution, study how other solutions behave in its neighbourhood, make equations linear to study what happens in first order.

Comment: Does this mean, for example for v, to consider $v_1=v+h\tilde{v}$, then compute $v_1'$ and so to get $\tilde{v}$ which is what we seek?

Comment: Sort of. You can write $h$, but also you can write $v = v_1 + \delta v$, compute time derivative and truncate higher order terms of $\delta v$. But you can use $h$ too :)

Comment: Why $v=v_1+\delta v$? What is that?

Comment: This is just a starting point for variation equation. You have your known solution $(u_1, v_1, w_1)$ and some other solution $(u, v, w)$. But it's "close" to $(u_1, v_1, w_1)$ and you want to study how it behaves in time: does it become closer to or runs away from $(u_1, v_1, w_1)$? This is how naturally $\delta u$, $\delta v$ and $\delta w$ appear: they measure difference between your distinguished solution $(u_1, v_1, w_1)$ and solutions in its neighbourhood. Feel free to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: And why is it the same to use what I wrote? Sorry- am a bit confused.

Comment: Because it's not that really different what to consider: $v_1 - v$ or $v -v_1$. Just changes signs. And you don't have to artificially create $h$ to write $o(h)$ when you can write $o(\| \delta v \|)$.

Comment: In fact, I do not even know what h is...

Comment: You might have chosen $\tilde{v}$ in such way that $\| \tilde{v} \| = 1$ and use $h$ as a scaling parameter :)

Comment: I thought v tilde is the derivarive and h the difference between v and v1 -- so taylor approximation ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a system

$$u'=v,~~~~~v'=-cv-f(u)+w,~~~~~w'=-(\epsilon / c)(u-\gamma w)$$

and some trajectory $(u_{\rm ref} (t), v_{\rm ref} (t), w_{\rm ref} (t) )$ 
which of course satisfies system of ODEs.
You want to study how nearby solutions behave w.r.t. to $(u_{\rm ref} (t), v_{\rm ref} (t), w_{\rm ref} (t) )$. For that you introduce quantitites $\delta u = u_{\rm ref} - u$, $\delta v = v_{\rm ref} - v$ and $\delta w = w_{\rm ref} - w$ -- these are your variations. You can differentiate all these (taking into account that you also have system of ODEs):

$$ \dot{\delta u} = \dot{u_{\rm ref}} - \dot{u} = v_{\rm ref} - v = \delta v, $$

$$ \dot{\delta w} = 
\dot{w_{\rm ref}} - \dot{w} = 
- \frac{\varepsilon}{c}\bigl ((u_{\rm ref} - u) - \gamma \cdot (w_{\rm ref} - w) \bigr) =
- \frac{\varepsilon}{c}(\delta u - \gamma \cdot \delta w). $$

So far so good, except that the last expression will cause troubles:

$$ \dot{\delta v} = \dot{v_{\rm ref}} - \dot{v} = 
(-cv_{\rm ref} + w_{\rm ref} - f(u_{\rm ref}))
-
(-cv + w - f(u)) =
-c \cdot {\delta v} 
+ \delta w
- \left ( f(u_{\rm ref}) - f(u) \right ).
$$

Everything is right and great, but we can't express it in terms of variations only. But we can linearize it and see what happens. We just write $f(u_{\rm ref}) - f(u) = f'(u_{\rm ref}) (u_{\rm ref} - u) 
+ o \left ( \| u_{\rm ref} - u \| \right ) \approx f'(u_{\rm ref}) \cdot {\delta u}$. And this gives us *a system of variation equations linearized along $(u_{\rm ref}, v_{\rm ref}, w_{\rm ref})$* . Depending on what solution $(u_{\rm ref} (t), v_{\rm ref} (t), w_{\rm ref} (t) )$ you plug in, you might get a system with constant coefficients (when you plug in equilibrium solution), periodic coefficients (when you plug in periodic solution) or just non-autonomous system of equations.

Comment: And now I do understand the connection to my second problem. By what you have explained me, we know the approximation is well for small $\lVert u_{\text{ref}}-u\rVert$. And if this is small then it is near $U_1$ for $\varepsilon =0$.